# Python empty list Exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, except

I have this function:

```
def foo():
    a = []
    if not a:
        print "empty"
        return None
    else:
        print "not empty"
        return a
```

Is there any Exception that do the same? Just to remove the if condition. Something like this:

```
def foo(list):
    try:
        a = list
        return a
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: Your first function doesn't make sense - `if not a:` will always be `True`...also, please don't use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Also, why do you want to return `None` instead of an empty list? An empty list already evaluates to a boolean `False`, so what's the reasoning behind your question?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you actually want to do with the list? *Why* do you want to check if it's empty?

Answer (score 11):

I would just use `return l if l else None`, you could try to index the list but I would not recommend it.

```
def foo(l):
    try:
        l[0]
        return l
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: It is better to not use just `except`, as it can hide unexpected errors. Use `except IndexError` instead.

Comment: @stalk, true, added, I would not use an except at all, it was just to show that it was possible.